# Sass File to import not found or unreadable

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, sass

I have the following files:

```
app/assets/stylesheets/common/application.css.sass
```

the first line of this file is:

> @import common

and the common file is on:

app/assets/stylesheets/common.css.sass

But if a make a trace like this:

```
sass --watch app/assets/stylesheets/common/application.css.sass --trace
```

I get the following error:

> error app/assets/stylesheets/common/application.css.sass (Line 1: File
>   to import not found or unreadable: common. Load path: /repos/blabloo)

I tried to import the common file using "../common" and "/../common"

but I still having the same problem.

How can I solve this, because I can't upload the files to the production server and I guessing this is the cause.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score -1):

You have to add **.css** to the name of your file.

```
@import common.css
```

You can omit the .sass or .scss extension, but in the other cases, you must add the extension.

Regards.

Comment: Thank you Mario, Know, I the application.css.sass can see the variables like my $darkgray color on my common file $darkgray: #404041